# Apply style to Windows Phone TextBox when it doesn't contain text

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to find out a way to apply a style to a TextBox element when it does not contain text. I want the TextBox to have a different background color (for instance) when it does or does not contain any text.

As Triggers are not something that I can use in Silverlight (afaik), is there another way to do this? Preferrably without writing a custom implementation of TextBox just for this behavior. Thanks.

---

I ended up using a default behavior (ConditionBehavior):

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ec:ConditionBehavior>
                <ec:ConditionalExpression>
                    <ec:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox}" RightOperand="" Operator="NotEqual"/>
                </ec:ConditionalExpression>
            </ec:ConditionBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ec:ConditionBehavior>
                <ec:ConditionalExpression>
                    <ec:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox}" RightOperand="" Operator="Equal"/>
                </ec:ConditionalExpression>
            </ec:ConditionBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Create a converter Binding to the Text Property, that swaps between styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fairly easy to accomplish with a custom behavior. Use [this link](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Behaviors-and-Triggers-in-Silverlight-3.aspx) to create a behavior that can be attached to a TextBox control. In the `OnAttached` method, you can handle the `TextChanged` event of even the `LostFocus` method to check whether the TextBox is empty or not. Accordingly, you can switch the style between the styles.

P.S: You *might* need to call the TextBox.ApplyTemplate() method after changing the style. Note sure about that though.

Comment: This answer helped me in the right direction, so I'm marking this as an answer. The solution I used is in the first post.

Answer (score 1):

Create your styles

```
  <Style x:Key="FilledStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Beige" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="EmptyStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Style>


 <Models:TextStyleConverter x:Key="TextStyleConverter" />
```

Create Converter

```
public class TextStyleConverter : IValueConverter
    {
    #region Implementation of IValueConverter

    /// <summary>
    /// Modifies the source data before passing it to the target for display in the UI.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The value to be passed to the target dependency property.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="value">The source data being passed to the target.</param><param name="targetType">The <see cref="T:System.Type"/> of data expected by the target dependency property.</param><param name="parameter">An optional parameter to be used in the converter logic.</param><param name="culture">The culture of the conversion.</param>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = value as string;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(val)) return Application.Current.Resources["EmptyStyle"];

        return Application.Current.Resources["FilledStyle"];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Modifies the target data before passing it to the source object.  This method is called only in <see cref="F:System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.TwoWay"/> bindings.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The value to be passed to the source object.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="value">The target data being passed to the source.</param><param name="targetType">The <see cref="T:System.Type"/> of data expected by the source object.</param><param name="parameter">An optional parameter to be used in the converter logic.</param><param name="culture">The culture of the conversion.</param>
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Usage

```
 <TextBox x:Name="locationtbx" Style="{Binding ElementName=locationtbx, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextStyleConverter}}"  />
```